# PostgreSql - Show all records for the next month

Tags: postgresql

I would like to show all records for the next month. For example the current month is April, I would to see all records for May. 
This snippet shows anything after the current date. 
Should I be using a BETWEEN function instead?

```
SELECT "ApptDate" FROM tblappt 
WHERE "ApptDate" > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 month';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE ApptDate >= DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' AND
      ApptDate < DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '2 MONTH'
```

Comment: That worked will mark as answered...But If I want to do the same for the previous month, would  I just  subtract the Intervals?

Comment: @TommyMcGee . . . Yes, that is the idea.